# Template template parameter simple example

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits, template-templates

First I was learning about template template parameters, and I started wondering if I had a `vector<vector<int>>`, if I could make a template that extracts out the type `int` from there.

But, in the process of trying to build an example, I can't even get a single-level template parameter template function to work!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template< 
    template<class> class C2,
    class I
>
void for_2d(const C2<I>& container) 
{
    for( auto j : container ){
        std::cout << j;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> cont;
    for_2d(cont);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces:

```
17 : <source>:17:5: error: no matching function for call to 'for_2d'
    for_2d(cont);
    ^~~~~~
8 : <source>:8:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure : template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter
void for_2d(const C2<I>& container) 
     ^
1 error generated.
Compiler exited with result code 1
```

Comment: Try vector::value_type -no need to complicate it.

Answer (score 6):

The thing you are missing is that vector has multiple template arguments (most of them has default value). 
You need to prepare your function for this

```
template< 
    template<class...> class C2,
    class I
>
void for_2d(const C2<I>& container) 
{
    for( auto j : container ){
        std::cout << j;
    }
}
```

Notice the dots after `class`

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the Bartosz Przybylski's answer, that explain why your example doesn't compile, but you want

> extracts out the type int from there

You use `auto j : container`, so you're using (at least) C++11; so I suggest you the implementation of a specific, and recursive, type traits.

I propose the following `firtType`
First of all, the generic (not specialized) version (that is the recursion terminal)

```
template <typename T>
struct firstType
 { using type = T; };
```

Next the specialization for `std::vector` and other containers similar container (that receiving a seguence of types)

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct firstType<C<T0, Ts...>>
 { using type = typename firstType<T0>::type; };
```

This specialization works with a lot of containers but not with `std::array`, that receive a type and a number; the following is a specialization for `std::array`

```
template <template <typename, std::size_t> class C, typename T, std::size_t N>
struct firstType<C<T, N>>
 { using type = typename firstType<T>::type; };
```

Other specializations may be required.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct firstType
 { using type = T; };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct firstType<C<T0, Ts...>>
 { using type = typename firstType<T0>::type; };

template <template <typename, std::size_t> class C, typename T, std::size_t N>
struct firstType<C<T, N>>
 { using type = typename firstType<T>::type; };

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<int>                 vi;
   std::array<long, 42U>            al;
   std::vector<std::vector<short>>  vvs;

   static_assert( std::is_same<typename firstType<decltype(vi)>::type,
                               int>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<typename firstType<decltype(al)>::type,
                               long>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<typename firstType<decltype(vvs)>::type,
                               short>::value, "!" );
 }
```